How can I fill a skewed comic panel with text using CSS?
I'm working on a practice project involving comic layouts, and I want to design a part of the page to look like a comic panel.
I've managed to skew the panel using transform: skew(10deg);, and I can unskew the contents with transform: skew(-10deg);. This gets me part of the way there, but I need the text to fill the skewed shape, similar to the sketch I've provided bellow.
How can I achieve this effect using CSS? Are there specific techniques or properties I should use to ensure the text fills the skewed panel correctly?
here's the design sketch.
Thank you for your time!
I came across shape-outside, but I couldn't figure out how to do the reverse.
here's what I have so far:


* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  background-color: teal;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  width: 70%;
}

.content {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.content>* {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <h2 class="card-title">cool title</h2>
      <p class="card-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed totam praesentium nisi quibusdam explicabo error officia veritatis ut facere nostrum, repellat iusto optio deserunt qui laboriosam maiores vel? Vel quis optio, nulla error totam explicabo
        ipsam neque eos non magni!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>




Could you provide us your code you have used. How to provide minimal code

I've added a quick code sample.

clip-path would be my got to. Work with the numbers and find out what fits the best.


* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.co/600x400/EEE/31343C);
  background-position: center;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  width: 70%;
}

.content {
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 42%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.content>* {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}

.card-desc {
  padding: 1rem;
}
<div class="card">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="card-title">cool title</h2>
    <p class="card-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed totam praesentium nisi quibusdam explicabo error officia veritatis ut facere nostrum, repellat iusto optio deserunt qui laboriosam maiores vel? Vel quis optio, nulla error totam explicabo
      ipsam neque eos non magni!</p>
  </div>




While clip-path works for the content container, the text is still not filling the skewed container. thanks though!

Ah ok. Then i did not read right. If i have time i will loook into it a bit more.
